# How to use lambda function on a pandas data frame via map/apply where lambda takes different values for each column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The idea is to transform a data frame in the fastest way according to the values specific to each column. 
For simplicity, here is an example where each element of a column is compared to the mean of the column it belongs to and replaced with 0 if greater than mean(column) or 1 otherwise.

```
In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))                                                                                                                                                               

In [27]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[27]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [28]: df.mean().values.tolist()                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[28]: [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
```

Snippet bellow, it is not real code but more to exemplify the desired behavior. I used `apply` method but it can be whatever works fastest.

```
In [29]: f = lambda x: 0 if x < means else 1                                                                                                                                                                               

In [30]: df.apply(f)

In [27]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[27]: 
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
```

This is a toy example but the solution has to be applied to a big data frame, therefore, it has to be fast.

Cheers!

Comment: `.apply` is almost always going to be your last resort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a boolean mask of the dataframe by comparing each element with the mean of that column. It can be easily achieved using

```
df > df.mean()

    0       1       2
0   False   False   False
1   True    True    True
```

Since True equates to 1 and False to 0, a boolean dataframe can be easily converted to integer using astype.

```
(df > df.mean()).astype(int)

    0   1   2
0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1
```

If you need the output to be some strings rather than 0 and 1, use np.where which works as (condition, if true, else)

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df > df.mean(), 'm', 'n'))

    0   1   2
0   n   n   n
1   m   m   m
```

Edit: Addressing qn in comment; What if m and n are column dependent

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))

    0   1   2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9   10  11

pd.DataFrame(np.where(df > df.mean(), df.min(), df.max()))

    0   1   2
0   9   10  11
1   9   10  11
2   0   1   2
3   0   1   2
```

Comment: It seems a very elegant solution! I need to understand how it works to make sure it does not mess up things. Can you explain it? What if instead of replacing the values with 0 and 1 I want to replace them with `n if x < mean` and `m otherwise`? How can I twist your solution?

Comment: Very elegant! Nice solution!

Comment: To push the solution one step further ...:)... what if `m` and `n` are column dependent? For example `m=min(column)` and `n=max(column)`.

Comment: @flamenco, not sure if I understand that. What would be the expected output?

Comment: I meant to say that `m` and `n` might not to fixed but could vary from column to column.

Comment: @flamenco, see the last edit, does that answer the last qn?